# Reloading images in the buttons present in the table view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

In my table view I have 4 `UIButton`s, 2 in each row of table view. Initially all the buttons have an image on them (they're hardcoded). Now there is a button in my app which when tapped replaces the images on the buttons with new ones using the `setImage` method and then reloads the table view. But unfortunately I am getting the old table view only i mean with old images. How can I get the new images on the buttons?

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation:-// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // if (cell == nil) {
    // cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    // }
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        button1=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,5,100,87)];
        [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BUTTON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickTo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.button1];

        button2=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135,5,100,87)];
        [button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TURN OFF.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickTo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button2];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        button3=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,5,100,87)];
        [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"JUMP.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickTo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button3];


        button4=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135,5,100,87)];
        [button4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CLOSE.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button4 addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickTo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button4];
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something here
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you put your cellForRowAtIndexPath implementation ?

Comment: i edited my question,please check and provide a solution plz

Comment: You are creating new buttons every time, you should create buttons only one time, then use them. 
Your code will get an existing cell (with new images) and add other buttons on it (with old images)

Try subcalssing UITableViewCell with buttons as attributes/properties

Comment: done like this but still not getting ,do i ahev to mention this setframe outside the cell for row at index path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably setting the image for the wrong state:

`[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

You need to set the correct value for `UIControlStateNormal` - where correct means the one that matches your buttons' current state(s).

Comment: done this way only ,then reloaded the table view but still got the old data in the table view

Answer (score 0):

It Seems that you have hardcoded images in cell for row method, so whenever you are reloading your tableview , they will have same images.

So If you like to change them then take a boolean varible and Update it like :

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  // if (cell == nil) {
  // cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  // }
  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }

  if(indexPath.row == 0)
  {
      button1=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,5,100,87)];

  ```
  [button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BUTTON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickTo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:self.button1];

  button2=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135,5,100,87)];
  [button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TURN OFF.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickTo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:button2];
  ```

  }
  else if(indexPath.row == 1)
  {
      button3=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,5,100,87)];
      [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"JUMP.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickTo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      [cell.contentView addSubview:button3];

  ```
  button4=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135,5,100,87)];
  [button4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CLOSE.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button4 addTarget:self action:@selector(ClickTo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:button4];
  ```

  }
  else
  {
      // Do something here
  }

if(myflag)
              {

[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"changedImage1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"changedImage2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"changedImage3"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"changedImage4"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

```
return cell;
```

}

// In Click to Method Set myflag yes and reload table

-(void)ClickTo:(IBAction )sender
{

myflag=YES;
  [tableview reloadData];

}